# How to prevent wrong audio file tag encoding after using SoX?

Tags: mp3, encoding, id3, sox

SoX changes tags. The title is changed from

```
4 марта
```

to

```
4 Ð¼Ð°ÑÑÐ°.
```

The SoX command is simple `sox f.mp3 f2.mp3`.

How to prevent wrong audio file tag encoding after using SoX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mid3iconv tool after SoX:

```
find -iname '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 mid3iconv -eCP1251 --remove-v1
```

Additional information is here: http://www.linuxrussia.com/2013/05/easy-tag-ubuntu.html.

Comment: Perfect, but I think the utf-8 is better choice:  `find . -name "*mp3" -print0 | xargs -0 mid3iconv -e utf-8 -d --remove-v1`